# Prevent character being drawn as emoji

Tags: android, unicode, android-canvas, draw, emoji

I want to draw a single unicode character to a canvas, using `drawText()`.

```
canvas.drawText("\u270c\ufe0e", x, y, paint);
```

On a test device running Android 7, it displays correctly:

[image: Correctly drawn character]

But in my emulator, "running" Android 6, and on a real device running Android 6, it gets drawn as Emoji, regardless of the `\ufe0e`:

[image: Character drawn as Emoji]

This is of course *not* what I want, since I want to have it drawn black, not pink! Is there any way to "switch off" Emojis when drawing text?

Comment: If you set black color on Paint object still it gets painted pink?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: @Bowi I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this other than the answer given below?

Comment: No. :-( I ended up using a pixel image instead of the char.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the EmojiCompat library, described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat) and [here](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-android-emoji-compatibility-library-1b9f3bb724aa). Add it to your dependencies;

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:27.1.1"
    ...
}
```

Initialize the library;

```java
EmojiCompat.init(new BundledEmojiCompatConfig(this).setReplaceAll(true));
```

And then replace `TextView` with `EmojiTextView`. Here's an example you can use to test:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <!-- replace -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="TextView - default: \u270c, text: \u270c\ufe0e, emoji: \u270c\ufe0f"/>

    <!-- with -->
    <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="EmojiTextView - default: \u270c, text: \u270c\ufe0e, emoji: \u270c\ufe0f"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If it doesn't work how you would like, remove `.setReplaceAll(true)` from the initialization line, try again, and see if that works.

EDIT:

If you want to draw the emoji text manually e.g. to a canvas, you can do it with `EmojiCompat.process(...)` and `android.text.StaticLayout`. I haven't tried it so there *might* be errors, but it should work.

```
// assuming x, y, and paint are defined
CharSequence emoji = EmojiCompat.get().process("\u270c\ufe0e");
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(emoji, paint, 
    canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
canvas.translate(x, y);
layout.draw(canvas);
canvas.translate(-x, -y);
```

Comment: This looks promising! But I do not have any TextView, I am drawing directly onto a Canvas. Does it work with a Canvas as well? How?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot try this at the moment: This is an old project without any Gradle support – downloading and processing the needed libraries by hand needs more time than I have at the moment. :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try Fontawesome. You won't need to download the whole library. Just the ttf file from the website. It's around 18MB.

https://fontawesome.com/get-started

Then you can use the strings in the cheat sheet to draw icons.

https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Copy the ttf file to your assets folder.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fontawesome_webfont_4.ttf");
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
canvas.drawText("\uf25b", x, y, paint);
```

You can find `\uf25b` in the cheatsheet as f25b. It's the peace icon.

Comment: This is a nice trick I haven't known yet. Yet, if I have to load external libraries or fonts, there is nothing gained from simply using a picture for the char I want to display which is exactly what I did in the end.